# Intra-page links not functioning correctly

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have an email that goes out weekly with a section at the top designed to link to the other sections of the email. However, when someone clicks the links, they scroll down the page a little bit, but don't stop at the correct section. An example of one of these links is below:

```
&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; <a href="#topics" style="white-space: nowrap">Featured Topic Page</a>
```

And the section that link is meant to reference is below:

```
<h2 style="font-size: 18px; color: #005883; margin: 0 0 12px; line-height: 22px" id="#topics">Featured Topic Page</h2>
```

I am new at this so please let me know if I should provide more information or if I should repost this in a different way! Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `#` from  `id="#topics"`

Comment: This is what our IT manager suggested as well - I tried it and it did not change anything. The link still scrolls the page down only a few lines, and it does not arrive at the referenced section.

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the ID of topics?

Comment: I double checked. I have 8 different elements that have "id=" but they are all different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Just remove the `id="#topics"` from your `h2` element and then it will work fine. Also make sure whether there is a proper space between these two elements otherwise you will not be able to catch the difference.

```html
&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
<a href="#topics" style="white-space: nowrap">Featured Topic Page</a>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 1000px;"></div><!-- Ignore this rule -->
<h2 style="font-size: 18px; color: #005883; margin: 0 0 12px; line-height: 22px" id="topics">Featured Topic Page</h2>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: If I do that, how does the anchor in the first section know what to reference? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: It is the rule. If you want to link to an internal element on your site, you should firstly give a id to the element which should be seen when you click on a link or button. Then you have to give a href attribute to the place where you want to click. When you give that href value, it should start from #. Otherwise your browser will not understand that this is a internal element and it will search for something like YOUR_WEBSITE_URL+HREF_VALUE. In here it will be something like "https://yoursite.com/topics/". But we need to go to https://yoursite.com#topics. That is the difference.